# NetSuite subsidiary value comparison in free marker

Tags: pdf-generation, freemarker, netsuite

Using the advanced PDF template to generate invoice template in NetSuite. Trying to display content based on subsidiary value but not sure how to check for the subsidiary internal ID value: Error: Expecting a number here...

```html
<#if record.subsidiary?number==1>
  Content 1
</#if>
<#if record.subsidiary?number==2>
  Content 2
</#if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `?number` on the end of a field tries to convert the value to a number.  In your case it's trying to convert the 'name' of the subsidiary to a number and this conversion fails.  Try this:

```
<#if record.subsidiary.id = '1'>
  Content 1
</#if>
<#if record.subsidiary.id = '2'>
  Content 2
</#if>
```

Notice that `record.subsidiary.id` is still a string so I'm still doing a string comparison.